# Not able to download apps on Lumia 535

Tags: apps, store, nokia-lumia-535

I'm not able to download any app on my phone (Lumia 535). The preexisting apps are the only apps I am able to update or reinstall. After I select the install button in the store it goes to the downloads section and it gives the message that its pending and never downloads. After some time it says " Attention required. Please try again." Whereas If i reinstall or update whatsapp or the ola app it gets done in a jiffy.

What could be the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Windows 10 or 8(.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1. Downloading via Wi-Fi and not cellular network.
2. Assure that you have the correct time and date.
3. Setting the correct time and date manually.
4. Install on phone memory instead of memory card (or vice versa).
5. Checked that your phone successfully runs its backups. If backup fails then Windows Phone can refuse to do several things, including doing update.
6. Restarting your phone after doing any of the other bullets.
7. Do a soft reset.
8. (Do a hard reset.)

Answer (score 2):

A possible option is to reset your phone. If you have important files that you want to keep, just put them on OneDrive which is pre-installed. So, when you did the reset, you can connect to OneDrive again and get your files back. After the reset, try to download an app on the Store. If it didn't work, you can also try to find a download of the app on the Internet.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't allow you to download the xap and install it if I am right

Comment: Not always but you could try